# Getting creation-SQL of a table in HP Vertica using a query

Tags: sql, vertica

I am using HP Vertica db engine. There are some tables created in the database. I have a requirement wherein I need to get the create-table script of a table given the table name by querying over a system-table or a stored-proc or otherwise. Any help in reaching this need is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to get the table definition for a table is by using [`EXPORT_TABLES()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/CopyExportData/ExportingTables.htm?Highlight=export_table). This function allows multiple objects for the scope.

You can script the export statement and execute it inside a script, such as:

```
SELECT 'SELECT EXPORT_TABLES('''', ''' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ''');' FROM v_catalog.tables;
```

Alternatively, you can roll up to the schema level using:

```
SELECT EXPORT_TABLES('', 'schema');
```

The difference being that `EXPORT_TABLES` will not produce definition for any projections associated with the table. If you need the projection with the table definition, use [`EXPORT_OBJECTS`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/CopyExportData/ExportingObjects.htm).

Comment: Also, can you provide a query in order to get the creation-date of a table, given the table-name? Thanks.

Comment: @NishanthReddy If you have another question, please use the **Ask Question** button.